# Using Redis as intermediary cache for REST API

Tags: django, rest, redis

We have an iOS app that talks to a django server via REST API. Most of the data consists of rather large Item objects that involve a few related models that render into single flat dictionary, and this data changes rarely.

We've found, that querying this is not a problem for Postgres, but generating JSON responses takes a noticeable amount of time. On the other hand, item collections vary per-user.

I thought about a rendering system, where we just build a dictionary for Item object and save it into redis as JSON string, this way we can serve API directly from redis (e.g. HMGET(id of items in user library), which is fast, and makes it relatively easy to regenerate "rendered instances", basically just a couple of `post_save` signals.

I wonder how good this design is, are there any major flaws in it? Maybe there's a better way for the task?

Comment: how big are the json responses and how long does it take to dump json ?

Comment: say around 300 dicts with 20 keys in them with some nested dicts, both tastypie and django-rest-framework render those for up to 1s on MBPr

Comment: did you try to use cjson or ultra json already ?

Comment: yes, the bottleneck is not json rendering, but the transformation from django model to a dictionary instance provided by aforementioned frameworks, I can't just use __dict__ either because there are a number of transformations involved

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sure, we do the same at our firm, using Redis to store not JSON but large XML strings which are generated from backend databases for RESTful requests, and it saves lots of network hops and overhead.

A few things to keep in mind if this is the first time you're using Redis...

**Dedicated Redis Server**
Redis is single-threaded and should be deployed on a dedicated server with sufficient CPU power. Don't make the mistake of deploying it on your app or database server.

**High Availability**
Set up Redis with Master/Slave replication for high availability. I know there's been lots of progress with Redis [cluster](http://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec), so you may want to check on that too for HA.

**Cache Hit/Miss**
When checking Redis for a cache "hit", if the connection is dead or any exception occurs, don't fail the request, just default to the database; caching should always be 'best effort' since the database can always be used as a last resort.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! What kind of load do you have on your redis servers? We're just starting and so far it looks like one EC2 instance is enough

Comment: Redis will be the last place you'll experience any bottlenecks. Our redis server runs on RedHat Linux Enterprise with 1 dual-core CPU/4GB RAM; based on our testing, 25K writes in under second and twice that for reads based on our payloads (25-100Kb) and Redis doesn't even break a sweat; it totally kicks ass.